# is there a way to save only the model with huggingface trainer?

Tags: huggingface-transformers

I want to keep multiple checkpoints during training to analyse them later but the `Trainer` also saves other files to resume training. Is there a way to only save the model to save space and writing time?

```sh
 15K  rng_state.pth
 906  trainer_state.json
 623  scheduler.pt
2,1G  optimizer.pt
2,5K  training_args.bin
1,1G  pytorch_model.bin
 900  config.json
```

I could just delete the optimizer after training but i'm also working with a disk with slower write speed so this is also a consideration

Answer (score 8):

Unfortunately, there is currently no way to disable the saving of single files. There are basically two ways to get your behavior:

1. The "hacky" way would be to simply disable the line of code in the `Trainer` source code that stores the optimizer, which (if you train on your local machine) should be [this one](https://github.com/huggingface/transformers/blob/master/src/transformers/trainer.py#L1587). However, whenever you update your transformers version, this could lead to ugly behavior, which is why I recommend the second one.
2. Overwrite the `_save_checkpoint()` function in your own `Trainer` object. This way, you always guarantee that the correct files are saved, and don't have to interact with the library's code.

An outline for what this looks like:

```py
from transformers import Trainer
class OwnTrainer(Trainer):
   # Don't forget to correctly set up __init__()
   # ...

   def _save_checkpoint(self, model, trial, metrics=None):
       # insert your own behavior here
```

Comment: `_save_checkpoint()` could be an option but it's still intended to be private and overriding it entails copying some parts that could also be updated in newer versions (including for some reason the mechanism to determine the best checkpoint)

Comment: Yes, that is accurate, but at least it clearly separates your *own* implementation from the library, which is a partial improvement. As there is currently no other way (other than to write the *entire* trainer yourself), I am afraid you're going to have to take care of any future updates regardless...

Answer (score 0):

As of version 4.37 they've added a `save_only_model` parameter to TrainingArguments, which doesn't save optimizer.pt/scheduler.pt or similar which can take up a lot of the storage space. Still saves some tokenizer files I believe, but a simple library supported adjustment you could make to save space.

```
save_only_model (bool, optional, defaults to False) — When checkpointing, whether to only save the model, or also the optimizer, scheduler & rng state. Note that when this is true, you won’t be able to resume training from checkpoint. This enables you to save storage by not storing the optimizer, scheduler & rng state. You can only load the model using from_pretrained with this option set to True.
```